# Where do exegetical questions on an apocryphal text belong?

Tags: discussion, site-definition

The question [What is the “head-band” Judith gives to Anna in the Protoevangelium of James?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/77368/what-is-the-head-band-judith-gives-to-anna-in-the-protoevangelium-of-james) about one of the more famous NT apocryphal text is valid and worthy of investigation.

But does the question belong in C.SE, in BH.SE, or neither?

In my opinion, the argument can be made for either:

1. It belongs in C.SE because one thesis I found about it linked this apocrypha to the later teachings and devotions to Mary being Mother of God.
2. It belongs in BH.SE because one thesis I found about it linked this apocrypha to a better understanding of purity, thus can have bearings on the interpretation of canonical texts.

Comment: [What texts are open for examination?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/2757) on the BH.SE Meta site.

Comment: @curiousdannii  Thanks.  I couldn't find that question.  So probably that question needs to be moved to BH.SE then.

Comment: I'd migrate if someone flagged it or something.  I don't like doing it without an obvious trail.